# Ссылки(Указатели) в JAVA. Применение ссылочных переменных

Tags: java, указатели, ссылки

Есть задача: Реализовать функцию, которая читает длинное число. Все сделал, вот только нужно решить ее при помощи ссылок.То есть, чтобы вместо `char[] s` и `int[] a` были ссылки и менялись их значение. В С++ это выглядит так `void ReadLong(char *s,int *a);` А как это сделать в java?

```
public static int size;

    public static void ReadLong(char[] s,int[] a) {
        int cnt;
        if (s.length%4==0) {
            cnt=s.length/4;
        }
        else {
            cnt = (s.length+4-s.length%4)/4;
        }

        a[0]=cnt;
        int num=1;
        int ost=s.length%4;
        int i=0;
       while (s.length-i>ost) {
            a[num] = Character.getNumericValue(s[i]) + Character.getNumericValue(s[i + 1]) * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(s[i + 2]) * 100 + Character.getNumericValue(s[i + 3]) * 1000;
            i+=4;
            num++;
        }
        switch (ost){
            case 1:
                a[num]=Character.getNumericValue(s[i]);
                break;
            case 2:
                a[num]=Character.getNumericValue(s[i])+Character.getNumericValue(s[i+1])*10;
                break;
            case 3:
                a[num]=Character.getNumericValue(s[i])+Character.getNumericValue(s[i+1])*10+Character.getNumericValue(s[i+2])*100;
                break;
            default:break;
        }
        for (int j=1;j<=cnt;j++) System.out.println(a[j]);
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       String s=in.nextLine();
       StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder(s);
       S.reverse();
       char[] ss = S.toString().toCharArray();
        int cnt = s.length()/4+2;
        size=cnt;
        int[] a = new int[cnt];
        ReadLong(ss,a);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все аргументы в Java передаются **при вызове по значению**.

> Когда методу передается ссылка на объект, **сама ссылка передается
>   способом вызова по значению**. Но поскольку передаваемое значение
>   ссылается на объект, то копия этого значения все равно будет ссылаться
>   на тот же самый объект, что и соответствующий аргумент.

---

> То есть, чтобы вместо `char[] s` и `int[] a` были ссылки и менялись их значение

В данном случае в метод передаются копии ссылок. При изменении этих массивов в методе, **эти изменения будут видны извне** (Вы можете проверить это самостоятельно, выведя на консоль элементы массивов до и после).

**Передать параметр при вызове по ссылке в Java невозможно.**

Пример 1:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = 1;
        }

        printArray(array);

        System.out.println("changeArray");

        changeArray(array);

        printArray(array);
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] array) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    private static void changeArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
[1, 1, 1]
changeArray
[2, 2, 2]
```

Из этого примера видно, что после изменения массива с помощью метода `changeArray(...)` эти изменения видны в методе `main(...)`.

Пример 2:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = 1;
        }

        printArray(array);

        System.out.println("changeArray");

        changeArray(array);

        printArray(array);
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] array) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    private static void changeArray(int[] array) {
        array = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
[1, 1, 1]
changeArray
[1, 1, 1]
```

Этот пример четко демонстрирует тот факт, что аргумент передается при вызове по значению (**а не при вызове по ссылке**). Если бы массив передавался при вызове по ссылке, то изменение ссылки в методе `changeArray(...)` было бы видно в методе `main(...)`, однако оно не видно, так как в методе `changeArray(...)` была изменена **копия ссылка** на массив.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @NikitaKuz "большое спасибо" располагается в левом верхнем углу ответа